# "Property value is not valid." Why is visual studio not letting me assign a picture to an image?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010

On a WPF window I have an image object. I clicked the button to assign a source, the window for it popped up, I added the image in there (clicking add). When the image loaded in, instead of showing the image, it just showed a white box. I try to assign this white box as the image source, and it just says "property value is not valid." The solution explorer clearly shows that the images are there, and I can double click and open to edit them. So why isn't VS liking how I'm trying to assign images to my wpf image object? I've added images to WPF projects several times using this method.

Comment: it's almost impossible to help you based on this description. If you have worked this out elsewhere copy the wpf-xaml into the new place and change the image-name. Or try to add the xaml-code with a good description and maybe some screenshots to your question...

Comment: @CarstenKönig I haven't touched the xaml myself, I just dragged an image over from the toolbox, and clicked its source button in the properties window.

Comment: yeah thought so - but take the xaml from a working picture - copy&paste and change the path - should be a no brainer

Comment: @CarstenKönig Yes it works if I hardcode the image path in there myself. What I'm trying to figure out is why VS doesn't want to see any of these images in the "choose image" window that opens when you want to pick the image source.

Comment: it's very hard to answer this - I guess if we'd see the project for ourselves the problem would be more or less easy to find - but having only your description of the symptom without any background on the project/setup/etc. of your solution? Like diagnosing cancer if the patient tells the doctor on the phone "I'm sick"

Comment: @CarstenKönig I should point out that it's a brand new project, albeit on a computer that VS was newly installed on, so I assumed it was not something project specific. But it was, it wasn't working because there was a space in the solution name. You'd think VS would be designed to handle something like that.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In case other people read this, **restarting the Visual Studio** might help.

Answer (score 2):

So, it turns out the reason for this particular error was there was a space in my solution name. I guess this caused there to be a space in the path for the image, which VS just couldn't handle. Odd, but that was it.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem just now with VS 2012. It was traced to the fact that I'd given one of my `UserControl`s a `NameProperty` of "This", in order to internally reference some dependency properties I'd defined for the controls.

Don't give your `UserControl`s a `Name="This"` property in XAML. It gets confooosed.

Comment: Yeeaaa that would be a bad idea. I had a similar problem with using a SQL table named System and then having the Entity Framework create a System object..

Comment: x:Name="Self" is my convention for all top-level elements. Very useful approach, in my experience.

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same issue. Because the pictures are being referenced by the project as resources they need to be compiled into the project. So in my case I added them to the solution, then built the project. At that point they were available to assign to the image control.

Comment: Indeed, happened to me (in a similar context) recently as well.